# Showing boundedness in $\mathbb{R}^2$ implies totally boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, alternative-proof

Here's my attempt at a proof:

Let $A$ be a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then there exists $L>0$ such that $A \subset [-L,L] \times [-L,L]$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. I intend to cover $A$ by "little" squares of diameter at most $\varepsilon$.

Suppose the edge length of little square be $\varepsilon_{0}$. Since the diameter of squares is nothing but the length of the diagonal, we want $\varepsilon_{0} ^2 + \varepsilon_{0} ^2 < \varepsilon ^2$, i.e, $\varepsilon_{0} < \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Clearly, $[-L,L]$ is covered by $[-L, -L + \varepsilon_{0}]$, $[-L+\varepsilon_{0} , -L + 2\varepsilon_{0}]$, ... , $[-L+(n-1)\varepsilon_{0}, -L + n\varepsilon_{0}]$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $n\varepsilon_{0} \ge 2L$. Now, it is clear that $A \subset [-L,L] \times [-L,L]$ is covered by cartesian product of the covering of $[-L,L]$ and $[-L,L]$. The covers are nothing but the "little" squares that we wanted.

Is this proof correct? **Alternative proofs are welcome.**

Comment: Well, really you need to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ that there is a finite $\epsilon$-net. It might be more straightforward to take $A \cap {1 \over2} \epsilon \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: The proof looks fine, except for a couple small points: you want $2\epsilon_0^2 < \epsilon^2$, not $< \epsilon$; also, the 2D covering is the **cartesian product**, not the union.

Comment: @ErickWong thanks for suggestions. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof.

Let $\epsilon>0$

Since $A$ is bounded then $\bar{A}$ is compact thus totally bounded,thus exist $x_1,x_2,...,x_m$ such that $\bar{A} \subseteq B(x_1,\epsilon/8) \cup...\cup B(x_m,\epsilon/8)$

Now for $n=1,2,...,m$ take $y_n \in A$ such that $|y_n-x_n| <\frac{\epsilon}{8}$

So $B(x_n,\epsilon/8) \subseteq B(y_n,\epsilon/4)$ and $A \subseteq B(y_1,\epsilon/4) \cup...\cup B(y_m,\epsilon/4)$

In the plane each disk with radius $r$ and center $x$ is the subset of the  square centered at $x$ and has diameter $3r$.

So you have the coverings with squares with diameter $\frac{3\epsilon}{4}<\epsilon$